# Encrypted in Java and decrypting the same string in BigQuery not working

Tags: java, encryption, google-bigquery, google-cloud-kms

We have some columns which need encryption when pushed to BigQuery. For that we're using column level encryption.

So, when we push the data to BigQuery via java, the data is encrypted when it is pushed. However when we try to decrypt the data using select statements in BigQuery, the decryption fails.

Java cipher text:

```java
KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create();

CryptoKeyName cryptoKey = CryptoKeyName.of("project", "region", "column-encryption-keyrings", "column-encryption-key");

EncryptResponse response = client.encrypt(cryptoKey, ByteString.copyFromUtf8("abcde"));

String encryptedCipher = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(response.getCiphertext().toByteArray()))
```

Using BQ for decryption:

```sql
SELECT
  DETERMINISTIC_DECRYPT_BYTES(
    KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(kms_resource_name, first_level_keyset),
    encryptedCipher,
   ''
  ) AS decryptedData
```

The error that we get is decryption failed.

Firstly is this even possible? If yes, is there something that I'm missing?

-- Updated:
Have updated the code where I'm encrypting. The same encryptedCipher string I copy from the logs and try to decrypt in BigQuery, where I get the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Your post misses the encryption Java code. `getCiphertext` is not a standard J2SE method, so it is unclear what library you use.

Comment: Have updated the code where I'm encrypting.

Comment: Do this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#kms-encrypt-symmetric-java) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions#deterministic_decrypt_bytes) help you?